# Assign a vector to a variable based on criteria

Tags: r, if-statement

```
  top5 <- ifelse(state = "PA", c("Oranges", "Bananas", "Avocados", "Tomatoes", "Cucumbers"),
             ifelse(state = "MA"), c("Oranges", "Bananas", "Peaches", "Leaves", "Cucumbers"),
             ifelse(state = "ME"), c("Oranges", "Bananas", "Avocados", "Tomatoes", "Watermelon"),
             ifelse(state = "NH"), c("Tea", "Bananas", "Avocados", "Tomatoes", "Cucumbers"),
             ifelse(state = "RI"), c("Oranges", "Coconuts", "Avocados", "Tomatoes", "Cucumbers"),
             ifelse(state = "VT"), c("Carrots", "Bananas", "Apples", "Tomatoes", "Cucumbers"))
```

The above is currently what I have. I'd like to assign the corresponding vector based on the input into the function. I am putting this inside a function, although I can not get it to work even outside the function.Thank you.

In response to the answers, which are great solutions. However, I am looking to pass one of these vectors into a variable based on a criteria, which is not working.

The reason that I need to do this is to call the vector later on to filter my data for that state by the corresponding vector that matches the state.

For example PA's top five fruits are: "Oranges", "Bananas", "Avocados", "Tomatoes", "Cucumbers". I need that assigned to a variable if the function calls for PA, so that the function can later filter the data to only those fruits. Here is my full code:

```
FruitAnalyses <- function(statefile,state) 
top5 <- ifelse(state = "PA", c("Oranges", "Bananas", "Avocados", "Tomatoes", "Cucumbers"),
         ifelse(state = "MA"), c("Oranges", "Bananas", "Peaches", "Leaves", "Cucumbers"),
         ifelse(state = "ME"), c("Oranges", "Bananas", "Avocados", "Tomatoes", "Watermelon"),
         ifelse(state = "NH"), c("Tea", "Bananas", "Avocados", "Tomatoes", "Cucumbers"),
         ifelse(state = "RI"), c("Oranges", "Coconuts", "Avocados", "Tomatoes", "Cucumbers"),
         ifelse(state = "VT"), c("Carrots", "Bananas", "Apples", "Tomatoes", "Cucumbers"))

  statefile <- fread(paste0(state,"_fruit.csv"), header = T, data.table = F, 
stringsAsFactors = F, na.strings = c(",,",""," ")) 
#Lower names and convert to tbl
names(statefile) <- tolower(names(statefile))
statefile <- as.tbl(statefile)
#Parse Month and Year into single string - This is for later use when 
dates <-mdy(statefile$fruitstartdate)
statefile <- statefile %>%
 mutate(Month = month(dates, label = T))
rm(dates) 
statefileGrouped <- statefile %>%
  filter(priorfruitgroup %in% top5) %>%
  group_by(priorfruitgroup, Month) %>%
   summarise(TotalSeriousFruit = sum(seriousfruit),
            TotalFruitCount = sum(fruit)) %>%
  arrange(Month)
fwrite(statefileGrouped,file=paste0(state,".csv"))
barplot <- ggplot(statefileGrouped, aes(x=Month, y=Totalfruitcount, 
   fill=TotalotherfruitCount)) +
  geom_bar(color="black",stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(.~priorfruitgroup)
return(barplot)
}
```

Ignore the discrepancies in variable names, I had to change some names for confidentiality reasons. That is not the main topic of the question however. I am wondering why the top5 will not assign correctly to a vector based on criteria.

Comment: I think a possible solution is to group everything into lists and then call it into my variable: top5 <- paste0("top5$PA"). However, how do I coerce the string into an object?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `ifelse`, I would probably opt for the [`switch`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/switch.html) function:

```
states <- c('PA', 'MA', 'ME', 'NH', 'RI', 'VT')

sapply(states, function(x){
  switch(x,
         PA = c("Oranges", "Bananas", "Avocados", "Tomatoes", "Cucumbers"),
         MA = c("Oranges", "Bananas", "Peaches", "Leaves", "Cucumbers"),
         ME = c("Oranges", "Bananas", "Avocados", "Tomatoes", "Watermelon"),
         NH = c("Tea", "Bananas", "Avocados", "Tomatoes", "Cucumbers"),
         RI = c("Oranges", "Coconuts", "Avocados", "Tomatoes", "Cucumbers"),
         VT = c("Carrots", "Bananas", "Apples", "Tomatoes", "Cucumbers"))
})

     PA          MA          ME           NH          RI          VT         
[1,] "Oranges"   "Oranges"   "Oranges"    "Tea"       "Oranges"   "Carrots"  
[2,] "Bananas"   "Bananas"   "Bananas"    "Bananas"   "Coconuts"  "Bananas"  
[3,] "Avocados"  "Peaches"   "Avocados"   "Avocados"  "Avocados"  "Apples"   
[4,] "Tomatoes"  "Leaves"    "Tomatoes"   "Tomatoes"  "Tomatoes"  "Tomatoes" 
[5,] "Cucumbers" "Cucumbers" "Watermelon" "Cucumbers" "Cucumbers" "Cucumbers"
```

Which can be manipulated as follows:

```
xx <- sapply(states, function(x){
  switch(x,
         PA = c("Oranges", "Bananas", "Avocados", "Tomatoes", "Cucumbers"),
         MA = c("Oranges", "Bananas", "Peaches", "Leaves", "Cucumbers"),
         ME = c("Oranges", "Bananas", "Avocados", "Tomatoes", "Watermelon"),
         NH = c("Tea", "Bananas", "Avocados", "Tomatoes", "Cucumbers"),
         RI = c("Oranges", "Coconuts", "Avocados", "Tomatoes", "Cucumbers"),
         VT = c("Carrots", "Bananas", "Apples", "Tomatoes", "Cucumbers"))
})

apply(t(xx), 1, paste, collapse = ', ')

                                                PA 
 "Oranges, Bananas, Avocados, Tomatoes, Cucumbers" 
                                                MA 
    "Oranges, Bananas, Peaches, Leaves, Cucumbers" 
                                                ME 
"Oranges, Bananas, Avocados, Tomatoes, Watermelon" 
                                                NH 
     "Tea, Bananas, Avocados, Tomatoes, Cucumbers" 
                                                RI 
"Oranges, Coconuts, Avocados, Tomatoes, Cucumbers" 
                                                VT 
   "Carrots, Bananas, Apples, Tomatoes, Cucumbers"
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use a list.

```
my.list <- list("PA"=c("Oranges", "Bananas", "Avocados", "Tomatoes", "Cucumbers"),
                "MA"=c("Oranges", "Bananas", "Peaches", "Leaves", "Cucumbers"),
                "ME"= c("Oranges", "Bananas", "Avocados", "Tomatoes", "Watermelon"),
                "NH"=c("Tea", "Bananas", "Avocados", "Tomatoes", "Cucumbers"),
                "RI"=c("Oranges", "Coconuts", "Avocados", "Tomatoes", "Cucumbers"),
                "VT"=c("Carrots", "Bananas", "Apples", "Tomatoes", "Cucumbers"))
```

Which can then be accessed like this:

```
my.list$NH
[1] "Tea"       "Bananas"   "Avocados"  "Tomatoes"  "Cucumbers"
```

or:

```
x <- 'PA'
my.list[[x]]
```

when using variables.